# Documentation packages - where they are installed? [12.04, but probably applies to all debian-based distros]

Tags: documentation

When I install a package *-doc, eg libopencv-doc - where the documentation is placed? On Arch Linux it was /usr/doc, but I can't find it on Ubuntu. /usr/share/doc containst only changelogs :(
Or it's just man entry?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `dpkg-query -L libovpencv-doc`  This will list the full path to the installed files.n  The file should be under `/usr/share/doc/libopencv-doc`.